# wp_query initial leter of title

Tags: php, wordpress

What I am trying to do is create a wp_query so that the results are only of the initial letter of the title.

This is how I displayed & hyperlinked the letters & numbers..

```
<div class="align_Center">

<?php $args = array(
"0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z","ALL"           ); ?>

<?php

for($x = 0; $x < 37; $x++) { ?>

<span style="color: #777;">&nbsp;|&nbsp;</span>

<a href="../page-title-<?php echo $args[$x]; ?>" class="movie_lists"><?php echo $args[$x]; ?></a>

<?php } ?>

<span style="color: #777;">&nbsp;|</span>

</div>
```

And this is my test page..

```
<div class="col-md-6">      

<!-- ############################################## -->
<!-- ############### PAGE TITLE T ################# -->
<!-- ############################################## -->

<p class="f_header">PAGE TITLE T</p>

<?php

    global $wpdb;
    $first_char = 'T';
    $postids = $wpdb->get_col($wpdb->prepare("
    SELECT      ID
    FROM        $wpdb->posts
    WHERE       SUBSTR($wpdb->posts.post_title,1,1) = %s
    ORDER BY    $wpdb->posts.post_title",$first_char)); 

if ($postids) {
$args = array(

        'post__in'          => $postids,
        'post_type'         => 'post',
        'post_status'       => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page'    => -1,
        'caller_get_posts'  => 1

    );

    $query = new WP_Query( $args );

    if ($query->have_posts()) {

?>

<table width="100%"><!-- #### TABLE #### -->

    <?php

        while ($query->have_posts()) {

            $query->the_post();

    ?>

    <tr style="border-bottom: thin solid #111;">

        <td class="movie_genre">    

            <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>

        </td>

    </tr>

    <?php }; ?>

</table><!-- #### / TABLE #### -->

<?php }; wp_reset_postdata(); }; ?>
```

The test page is currently saved as page-title-t in the root theme dir at present it is not giving out any data whatsoever, so I am a bit baffled.

Comment: To perfom this in a project, I just used a Taxonomy and update it with the save hook... Not the best but it provide all the ULs you might need to do SEO works... 
You could also use a post meta

Answer (score 0):

The provided code is correct with the following general notes:

- You are stating that you are listing pages, but your query states `'post_type' => 'post'`. The `post_type` parameter accepts both string or array, so you can either witch to `'post_type' => 'page'` or `'post_type' => array('post','page')`
- Make sure your db collation is **case insensitive**, (*should end with _ci, e.g `utf8_general_ci`*) otherwise you should take care of small and capital letter queries (`t` and `T`)
- Additional note - `caller_get_posts` in the `$args` should be migrated to `ignore_sticky_posts` on *WordPress* version greater than **3.1.0**

Comment: if my code is correct then why when I click the hyperlink to the page-title-T do I view the index.php rather than the afore mentioned page.

Comment: This is another issue. You should have defined a custom permalink structure to be able to handle such `/page-title-T` page slugs.

Comment: didn't know that existed as I a new to wordpress.